# Should Includes/Require be at the Top of Code or Declared as Used Throughout? Readability vs. Effeciency?

Tags: php, coding-style, include

I've always thought that all of the includes should be at the top of your code. At a new job I see that they will use includes and create an instance of that class wherever they need it throughout the code.

Is it more efficient to use includes somewhere else, possibly under a control structure...

```
Ex. If ($monkey){
         include_once(banana.class.php);
         $old_banana = new banana;
    }
```

Then if monkey is never true the banana class doesn't ever need to be included.

What are best practices when it comes to this. (PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is for sure more efficient to use include/require only if you need it (inside control stuctures) however this can sometimes reduce the readibility of a script.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new feature in PHP 5.3 called  [__autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). You make instance of a class, php includes the instantiated class files. Thus you won`t have to worry if the file is included or not.

Comment: I don't think that's a new feature in 5.3... just sayin'.

Comment: I think it is from 5, but it is improved in 5.3

Answer (score 0):

As I review code from some big projects like joomla and community build, I see that they usually include only when they need. This is the way I prefer to code as I believe it is more efficient.